# What are the oldest living plants in the world today? What can you know about them? Why can some plants live so long?

Tags: botany

What are the oldest living plants in the world today? What can you know about them? Why can some plants live so long?

Comment: please ask only one question and try to be spesific,what type of research has you done so far.you have multiple questions here.

Comment: Arguably Pando, an aspen grove that is a single connected organism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree)  But for the many plants that spread by vegetative methods such as root suckers, the question of what exactly an individual plant is becomes rather difficult to answer.  For instance, I have many varieties of roses in my garden, all propagated (for instance, by rooting cuttings) from plants that were in some cases bred a century or two ago.  Are they still the same plant?

Comment: Just to be clear; you are asking for oldest individuals of plants, right? Not the oldest still living species (~living fossil)?

Answer (score 4):

[**Great Basin bristlecone pines**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinus_longaeva) (*Pinus longaeva*) have been known to live to be thousands of years old.

The oldest known living individual is named [Methuselah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah_(tree)) and is estimated to be more than 4,800 years old. It's been credited as the oldest living non-clonal organism on Earth.

There are [multiple other trees over 1000s years old](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_trees).